# How to write this formula in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode

Does anyone how to write this formula in Latex?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 8):

It looks to me like a `smallmatrix` environment was used.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'smallmatrix' env.

\begin{document}
$\mathcal{B} = (0.8 \begin{smallmatrix} +3.5 \\ -2.3 \end{smallmatrix} ) \times 10^{-5}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: OP might also consider the plain ``\mathcal{B} = ( 0.8\,_{-2.3}^{+3.5} ) \times 10^{-5}`` without any packages.